# Render ERB with underscore templates without displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, erb

Am trying to generate a PDF from a HTML file which itself is generated from dynamic content. So there is a controller action "generate_pdf" which takes HTML content and renders a PDF. The pdf generation bit works fine. Generating the HTML is where I am stuck.

```
#reports_controller.rb 
def generate_pdf
  @report = Report.where(:id => params[:id])
  html_content = render_to_string(:layout => false)

  #Use the html_content to generate PDF
end
```

Now the erb file is as follows :

```
#views/reports/generate_pdf.html.erb
This is the generated pdf from erb.
The following is a generated content. The report's id is <%= @report.id %>
and  the name is "<%= @report.name %>". </br>
It has <%= @report.items %> items.
```

This erb without any underscore templates works great and `render_to_string` generates correct HTML content.

But now if I use underscore.js templates ( the same report is also displayed in browser and the application uses Backbone.js and Underscore.js a lot) to generate the content of the report then `render_to_string` returns incorrect HTML. By incorrect, I mean, the output is the underscore.js template code itself and not the actual content.

```
{{ _.each(items, function(item) { }}
...
```

There is no JavaScript environment available inside `render_to_string` that would render the underscore.js templates. How can I handle this situation? Since most of our templates are in underscore.js, we thought it would make sense to reuse as much as of it as possible instead of creating a different template (in ERB ) just for PDF.

Comment: Would you please post code sample of a view with BB templates in it?